# For performance is using a macro better than using include with the 'with' statement?

Tags: performance, include, macro

Which is better for performance? Using a macro for output in a for loop or calling an include using the 'with' params to pass data? Both are loading a file. But is stacking up a bunch of code in a macro file faster than using an small include file?

```
{% for item in entries %}
    {% include "/components/_item" with { item: item } %}
{% endfor %}
```

OR

```
{% for item in entries %}
    {{ helpers.item(item) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say a macro would be faster because it's accessing the file system less.  In any case, unless you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of calls, I'd also guess that's the difference is going to be negligible for most use cases.